# How to change source of iframe and then reload, but a command instead of a link

Tags: php, iframe, hyperlink, webserver, ip

i have this code

```
if(stripos($text," on")!==FALSE){
//here it should goto 192.168.1.102/?dev=light?cmd=on
}
else{
//here it should goto 192.168.1.102/?dev=light?cmd=off
}
```

and i want it to open the address in an iframe, but not with a hyperlink to change the source of the iframe, but with a command, that will do it right away... can you guys please help me? :)
Victor

Comment: i am not following? this is only a part of the code... i just wont you to add what i need :)

Answer (score 0):

when you use php to run a code on server side, you make a full html page (tags, iframes & ...) and browser will be refreshed. you can set the new source for iframe in php code. if you want to change frame source without full refresh, you can use javascript on client side:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    document.getElementById('myframe').src = '192.168.1.102/?dev=light?cmd=on';
</script>
```

Comment: i tried, but this doesn't work :(
i also made ?> and <?php to it